# Automapper projection - multiple entities to view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, automapper

```
// combine User and Membership entities into a single class
public class CombinedEntities
{
    public User u { get; set; }
    public Membership m { get; set; }
}
// view model class
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //... other properties omitted 
}
// linq
var users = from u in dc.Users
             join m in dc.Memberships on u.UserId equals m.UserId
             select new CombinedEntities
             {
                u = u,
                m = m,
             };
// automapper config and mapping
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<CombinedEntities, MyViewModel>()
     .ForMember(x => x.Id , y => y.MapFrom(s => s.u.Id))
     .ForMember(x => x.UserGuid, y=> y.MapFrom(s => s.u.UserGuid)); 
     // should I keep adding more mapping here??
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var viewModels = mapper.Map<List<CombinedEntities>, List<MyViewModel>>(users.ToList());
```

I am wondering if I should keep adding mappings there. I don't think it'd bother me that much for only a couple of properties, but if we are talking about dozens, then doing so could be quite time-consuming and code looks bloated too.

Right now, I can think of 1) breaking down `CombinedEntities` class and keeping only properties in it; 2) simply not to use AutoMapper at all, and output `MyViewModel` list from linq directly.

Perhaps there's a better way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: From personal experience, using automapper == writing more code.

Comment: You are mapping much above the data source post fetching the data in the memory, how about doing at the source, if you are using micro orm like dapper, peta poco, they have good mechanism to do it automatically immediately post fetch

Comment: Even in the current system, you add a mapping for a property once, which in my view is not that much of work, since it would always keep mapping the values in the result accordingly